# What htop process colors mean

Tags: colors, htop

In `htop` some processes are displayed in red and others in blue. What is the meaning of these colors?

[image: htop process colors]

Comment: While blue isn't, red is covered in the [man page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/htop.1.html): "_The basename is marked in red if the executable used to run the process has been replaced or deleted on disk since the process started_"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A red process name means that the executable has been replaced or deleted since the process was started.
The blue (or cyan) that you are seeing is a highlight of the basename of the executable to make it easier to see.

Additionally, a yellow process name means that a library which is used by the process has been replaced or deleted since starting the process. This was added in version 3.1.0 of htop.

The Command highlight options and the meaning of red and yellow are explained [in the COLUMNS section of the man page](https://man.archlinux.org/man/htop.1.en#COLUMNS)

You can enable or disable these options under the "Display options" section of the htop Setup screen